# How do I make my C++ if-else work properly

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm a total beginner in C++.
I'm trying to make a Program that allows user to input a certain ID for a certain event and will get an answer based on the character/ID they input.
The problem I'm facing is that, only the first `if` of the 2 events is recognized. Meaning that no matter what the user input for the second event only the first answer will come out (Problem in line 93-119).

I'm sorry if it's too long I'm not sure from where I should copy, thanks.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//below are the variables used within main function and user-defined function
    int eventInput;
    int giftID;
    char receiverRole;
    char gifterName[100]; // [100] will allow input can be read up until 100 characters

//this is a user-defined function to create file output 
//this is output file, refer nota chapter 3 dari sir 
int getName (){
    // below is to fulfill file output in assignment criteria
        ofstream userData ("User Data.txt"); //creating file to store input from user in .txt file
        userData << "User's name: " << gifterName; //writing input from user into file that was had just been created
        userData.close(); 
        cout << endl;
} 

//this is a user-defined function to initiate the conversation with the user
void printIntro() {
    cout << "Hello! Welcome to Gift Guide!"<< "\n"; 
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << "First of all, I would love to get to know about you first" << endl << "What is your name?" << endl;
        cout << "My name is "; 
        cin.getline (gifterName, 100); //getting input from user: getting user's name
        int getName(); 
        cout << "Name is recorded!"; //letting the user know that their input has been recorded into .txt file
        cout << endl;
         
    cout << "Glad to be assisting you today, "<< gifterName << "! :D"<<endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Alright let's get started." << endl <<"Please answer the questions using ID given.";
    cout << endl;
}



//this is the main function
int main(){  
    
    printIntro();
    cout << "Is this for a special event?";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
        cout << "[ID: 1] I'm a secret santa! \n"
             << "[ID: 2] It's just for a good friend of mine.\n"
             << "[ID: 3] I'm buying a gift for my significant other. \n";

// below is a do-while repetition control structure
//to fulfill assignment criteria
//do-while starts here
//can refer nota chapter 5
 do {
        cout << "I choose: ";
        cin >> eventInput;
        cout << endl; 
        
        //below is to fulfill control structure (selection) in assignment criteria
        //this section's function is to choose gift for receiver based on the event selected 
    if (eventInput == 1){
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for 'Secret Santa' event. \n"
             << "[ID: 10] BRYSON SCREEN CLEANER \n"
             << "[ID: 11] BINARY WRIST WATCH FOR PROGRAMMERS \n"
             << "[ID: 12] DMOOSE CABLE MANAGEMENT BOX \n";
        
            cout << "Please choose your gift using the ID. \n";
            cout << "I choose: ";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;          
    } 
    else 
      {
        if (eventInput == 2){
            cout << "How would you precisely describe your friend? \n Please choose their role based on the ID given. \n"
             << "[ID: A] My friend is a Gamer. \n"
             << "[ID: B] My friend is a computer science major. \n"
             << "[ID: C] My friend is definitely a gadget junky. \n";
             
        cout << "My friend's description: ";
        cin >> receiverRole;
        cout << endl;  
        
        //STARTING FROM THIS PART: 
        //Explanation of this part: after the user choose EVENT 2, one of these outputs will be printed (A, B, or C)
        //Reason needed to debug:  Only choice A is working, choice B and C isn't working. Need to find a way to fix this.
        //This is if-else 
          if ("A" || "a"){
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for a gamer friend. \n"
             << "[ID: 01] Oculus Quest All-in-one VR Gaming Headset \n"
             << "[ID: 02] Kinesis Freestyle Edge RGB Split Gaming Keyboard \n"
             << "[ID: 03] Razer Basilisk v2 Wired Gaming Mouse \n";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;          
    } 
    else 
      {
        if ("B" ||"b"){
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for your friend. \n"
             << "[ID: 04] Kinesis Advantage2 Ergonomic Keyboard \n"
             << "[ID: 05] Das Keyboard 4 Professional \n"
             << "[ID: 06] Ergotron WorkFit-Z Mini Sit-Stand Desk \n";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;
        
        }else {
        
    if ("C" || "c"){
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for your friend. \n"
             << "[ID: 13] JE Wireless Smartphone Charger \n"
             << "[ID: 14] Bose Noise Canceling 700 Headphones \n"
             << "[ID: 15] Google Nest Wifi Router \n";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;   
    }
      }     
      //END OF EVENT 2 CHOICES
        
        } }else {
        
    if (eventInput == 3){
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for your significant other. \n"
             << "[ID: 07] MORSE CODE BRACELET \n"
             << "[ID: 08] LOVE HEART KEY CAP \n"
             << "[ID: 09] PERSONALIZE VIDEO PRINT \n";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;     
    }
      }      
    
} 
if (eventInput <= 0 || eventInput >= 3)
    cout << "Invalid event choice! Try again." << endl;
}
while (eventInput <= 0 || eventInput >= 4);
//do-while ends here
//as long as the user doesn't enter any other number than 1,2,3 then loop won't stop
}


//by the way, endl is a manipulator. You have to refer chapter 3 INPUT & OUTPUT note (page 5) dari sir to understand.
```

Comment: `else { if {} }` is awful syntax. Just use `else if {}` to start with. Comments like "this is the main function" are worthless.

Comment: `if("A" || "a")` is a longwinded way of saying `if(true)`. Did you mean something like `if(receiverRole == "A" || receiverRole == "a")` where you compare those strings to some variable? Although note that `receiverRole` is a `char` and `"A"` and `"a"` are strings, so you'll need to change one or the other to make the comparison work. It's harder to tell this because you declared `receiverRole` pointlessly far away from where it's actually used.

Comment: I think your code would become a lot more clear and therefore a lot easier to debug if you broke that logic up into multiple functions

Answer (score -1):

The gist of it is that in your option 2, your if statements are all `if (true)`, so you'll always enter the first one. You need to remember that a Boolean expression is expected, something that evaluates to `true` or `false`. `"A"` evaluates to `true` because it is not `0`.

You want your Boolean expressions to be something like:
`if (receiverRole == 'A' || receiverRole == 'a') {`

Note that `receiverRole` is a `char`, but `"A"` is a string literal, or `const char*`. They are not the same types, so I also changed the double quotes to single quotes to denote a `char`.

Below is a quick code review of what you submitted:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
// MISSING <fstream>
using namespace std;  // Bad Practice

/* 
 * Avoid globals if possible. Pass what you need to the
 * appropriate functions, or declare them in the functions.
 */
// This will be the only one of your comments I leave here; your comments are
// generally worthless. Comments should be about the why and not the what, as
// the what is plain to see by reading the code.

//below are the variables used within main function and user-defined function
    int eventInput;
    int giftID;
    char receiverRole;
    char gifterName[100];  // Prefer std::string

// A get function that gets nothing, is supposed to return an int, but returns
// nothing. The file will also only ever have one name recorded.
int getName (){
        ofstream userData ("User Data.txt");
        userData << "User's name: " << gifterName;
        userData.close();
        cout << endl;  // What's the point of this?
}

// Could probably just be in main(). It's called once and not in a loop.
void printIntro() {
    // Why is \n separate?
    cout << "Hello! Welcome to Gift Guide!"<< "\n";

    cout << endl;
    cout << "First of all, I would love to get to know about you first" << endl << "What is your name?" << endl;
        cout << "My name is ";
        cin.getline (gifterName, 100); //getting input from user: getting user's name
        int getName();
        cout << "Name is recorded!"; //letting the user know that their input has been recorded into .txt file
        cout << endl;

    cout << "Glad to be assisting you today, "<< gifterName << "! :D"<<endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Alright let's get started." << endl <<"Please answer the questions using ID given.";
    cout << endl;
}


int main(){

    printIntro();
    // Again, why have a printIntro() function that is incomplete?
    // Maybe the menu should be its own function and in the loop?
    cout << "Is this for a special event?";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
        cout << "[ID: 1] I'm a secret santa! \n"
             << "[ID: 2] It's just for a good friend of mine.\n"
             << "[ID: 3] I'm buying a gift for my significant other. \n";

 do {
 // Too many indents; poor formatting in general is likely sharing
 // some blame for the issues you're having.
        cout << "I choose: ";
        cin >> eventInput;
        cout << endl;

 // Inconsistent indentation and spacing throughout
    if (eventInput == 1){
        // You care about a valid choice at the first level, but not here.
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for 'Secret Santa' event. \n"
             << "[ID: 10] BRYSON SCREEN CLEANER \n"
             << "[ID: 11] BINARY WRIST WATCH FOR PROGRAMMERS \n"
             << "[ID: 12] DMOOSE CABLE MANAGEMENT BOX \n";

            cout << "Please choose your gift using the ID. \n";
            cout << "I choose: ";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;
    }
    // This is terrible syntax; just use else if {}
    else
      {
        // Each eventInput should go to its own function.
        if (eventInput == 2){
            cout << "How would you precisely describe your friend? \n Please choose their role based on the ID given. \n"
             << "[ID: A] My friend is a Gamer. \n"
             << "[ID: B] My friend is a computer science major. \n"
             << "[ID: C] My friend is definitely a gadget junky. \n";

        cout << "My friend's description: ";
        cin >> receiverRole;
        cout << endl;

        // This Boolean expression is if (true); you don't make a comparison.
        // receiverRole is a char, these are string literals
          if ("A" || "a"){
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for a gamer friend. \n"
             << "[ID: 01] Oculus Quest All-in-one VR Gaming Headset \n"
             << "[ID: 02] Kinesis Freestyle Edge RGB Split Gaming Keyboard \n"
             << "[ID: 03] Razer Basilisk v2 Wired Gaming Mouse \n";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;
    }
    else
      {
        if ("B" ||"b"){
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for your friend. \n"
             << "[ID: 04] Kinesis Advantage2 Ergonomic Keyboard \n"
             << "[ID: 05] Das Keyboard 4 Professional \n"
             << "[ID: 06] Ergotron WorkFit-Z Mini Sit-Stand Desk \n";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;

        }else {

    if ("C" || "c"){
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for your friend. \n"
             << "[ID: 13] JE Wireless Smartphone Charger \n"
             << "[ID: 14] Bose Noise Canceling 700 Headphones \n"
             << "[ID: 15] Google Nest Wifi Router \n";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;
    }
      }
        // This line below should be a hint to clean up your code.
        } }else {

    if (eventInput == 3){
            cout << "Gift suggestions below are suitable for your significant other. \n"
             << "[ID: 07] MORSE CODE BRACELET \n"
             << "[ID: 08] LOVE HEART KEY CAP \n"
             << "[ID: 09] PERSONALIZE VIDEO PRINT \n";
            cin >> giftID;
            cout << endl;
    }
      }

}

// Bad range; also the input is supposed to be a character?
if (eventInput <= 0 || eventInput >= 3)
    cout << "Invalid event choice! Try again." << endl;
}
// The range got worse?
while (eventInput <= 0 || eventInput >= 4);
}
```

I would normally post a fixed version, but this code is incredibly broken and missing a lot of key functionality. If I were to complete it and get it functioning, I'd both have to re-write it almost from scratch and add so much new code that I would have ended up completing your homework for you.